# start sevices after boot complete in linux mint

Tags: ubuntu, service, startup, systemctl, linuxmint

I am using linux mint 18.3 Sylvia.
My system is taking a long time to boot, as I found a lot of services are running at start up. What I am asking is there any way I could start those services after boot process is completed? Because I dont need those sevices (docker, postgres, mariadb, etc.) as the very first second of my desktop loads.

So, in short:

Is it possible to start service after boot process is completed? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Just FYI here is the output of `systemd-analyze blame`

```
     20.342s postgresql@9.6-main.service
     18.825s docker.service
     13.585s mariadb.service
     11.824s vmware.service
     11.807s ModemManager.service
     10.142s accounts-daemon.service
      7.194s dev-sda2.device
      6.056s polkitd.service
      5.859s NetworkManager.service
      5.736s apparmor.service
      5.728s apache2.service
      5.089s vmware-USBArbitrator.service
      4.720s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      4.235s virtualbox-guest-utils.service
      4.134s irqbalance.service
      4.047s ondemand.service
      4.046s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      3.275s media-mehedi-Development.mount
      3.253s media-mehedi-Tutorial.mount
      3.192s console-setup.service
      3.173s lightdm.service
      3.082s console-kit-log-system-start.service
      3.077s rsyslog.service
      3.076s lm-sensors.service
      3.075s systemd-user-sessions.service
      3.009s php7.0-fpm.service
      2.550s gpu-manager.service
      2.484s avahi-daemon.service
      2.046s vmware-workstation-server.service
      2.003s fruhod.service
      1.864s grub-common.service
      1.819s ntp.service
      1.754s thermald.service
      1.661s loadcpufreq.service
      1.563s speech-dispatcher.service
      1.388s redis-server.service
      1.282s lvm2-monitor.service
      1.192s keyboard-setup.service
      1.008s systemd-logind.service
       979ms pppd-dns.service
       970ms systemd-udevd.service
       957ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       920ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       910ms colord.service
       893ms binfmt-support.service
       783ms systemd-modules-load.service
       782ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       726ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7dd479a6\x2dbeb7\x2d4c24\x2dafe1\x2d22053bdace19.swap
       668ms systemd-journald.service
       523ms systemd-random-seed.service
       520ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       489ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by setting the time load of not necessary service after booting with below commands:

> systemctl editor docker.service

you need change *docker.service* which each service name you would.

then add below lines:

```
# docker.service time configuration override
[Timer]
OnBootSec=1min
OnUnitActiveSec=1d
AcuracySec=1h
RandomizedDelaySec=30min
```

save and exit.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable not needed services using
`systemctl disable service_name` and when you need once from disabled start it manually running
`systemctl start service_name`
Remember to run command with sudo or on root account.

Comment: this is a very bad and not useful answer. most of those services that in the startup, are useful and necessary.